# Looking for database of US companies

Tags: usa, business, companies, database

[Crunchbase](https://www.crunchbase.com/) looks most promising but they seem to be payware. Are there any free datasets of companies (established business & startups) to do some data science analysis? Ideally, the data should be name, a description of what it does, location(s), products/services offered etc.

I am looking for US businesses

Answer (score 3):

[Opencorporates](https://opencorporates.com/) is a good start, if you tell us more about the geographies you are interested in we might be able to help more.

Look also at the datasets listed [here](https://unigraph.io/datasets/), all trade registries are free and available to download if you follow the link from their logo.